# How to sort a dictionary by key?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

i tried to sort dict by key but no chance.
this is my dict :

```
result={'1':'value1','2':'value2',...}
```

i'm using Python2.7 and i found this

```
keys = result.keys()
keys.sort()
```

but this is not what i expected, i have an unsorted dict.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Standard Python dictionaries are inherently unordered. However, you could use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). It preserves the insertion order, so all you have to do is add the key/value pairs in the desired order:

```
In [4]: collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
Out[4]: OrderedDict([('1', 'value1'), ('2', 'value2')])
```

Comment: what if i had 1000 couple of (key, value) ??

Comment: what to do if I have to sort the `OrderedDict([('1', 'value1'), ('2', 'value2')])` in reverse order by `value*`

Answer (score 9):

```
sorted(result.iteritems(), key=lambda key_value: key_value[0])
```

This will output sorted results, but the dictionary will remain unsorted. If you want to maintain ordering of a dictionary, use [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Actually, if you sort by *key* you could skip the `key=...` part, because then the iterated items are sorted first by key and later by value (what NPE uses in his answer)

Comment: I'd personally go for `key=lambda (key,val): val)` which is also correct, but IMHO also more explicit

Comment: @JonClements that's deprecated in python 3 so the current approach is better

Comment: @jamylak: why is that deprecated? Any references?

Comment: @JakubM. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Comment: @JakubM. it was to do with unpacking references - the 3.x series disallowed such constructs as def f(somearg, (nextarg, otherarg))

Comment: Why not just sorted(result.iteritems())

Answer (score 3):

Python dictionaries are unordered (for definition)

You can use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead